# Implementation of summation sign

Tags: r

How can I implement something like this in R:

[image]

I am using this code:

```
i<-1000
4*(sum(1/i)*sin(i*x)))/pi
```

but it doesn't return what I am expecting

Comment: Take care with brackets: your `sum` ends after `1/i`

Comment: Take a look at what the [`sum` function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sum.html) actually does in R. your arguments are simply wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following function

```
series <- function(x, L=1, n_max=1000) {
   i <- seq(1, n_max, by=2)
   4*sum(sin(i*pi*x/L)/i)/pi
}
```

You may also be interested in examining the `fourier()` function from the `fda` package

Answer (score 1):

There are several unrelated issues with your implementation.

At first glance, you are simply implementing a completely different formula which does not at all correspond with your equation.

Secondly, take a look at what the [`sum` function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sum.html) actually does in R: your arguments are wrong.

But finally and more fundamentally, the sum itself iterates over the odd numbers 1,3,5…∞. This poses a problem: we cannot solve this sum through sheer computation, it has to be solved analytically. Unfortunately I’m not aware of any symbol equation solver for R which could handle this automatically, but you might want to give [Ryacas](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/) a shot.